# JavaScript objects used as hybrid data structures

Tags: javascript

I have a fairly decent knowledge of JavaScript and the prototypical inheritance that is used when initializing data structures, but I am still not completely sure how one of JS's unique functionalities works.

Lets say I create an array:

```
var myArr = [];
```

I can now push items to the array:

```
myArr.push('foo');
myArr.push('bar');
```

At this time `myArr.length == 2`

Now from there I can do something like

```
myArr['myProp'] = 5; // OR myArr.myProp = 5;
```

But my myArr.length still equals 2 and I can use some type of iteration method to iterate over the 2 values pushed initially.

So basically this object is a "hybrid" data structure that can be treated like an Array or an Object.

So my question is does the native Object syntax (`myObj.someProperty = 'blah'` OR `myObj['someProperty'] = 'blah'`), apply specifically to the Object.prototype and therefore ANY object inherited from that prototype? This would make sense because an Object's prototype chain looks like:

```
var myObj = {} -> Object.prototype -> null
```

And an Array's prototype chain looks like:

```
var myArr = [] -> Array.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null
```

Which would make me assume that anything you can do with an object (`myObj.someProperty //as getter or setter`) can be done with an Array which would then explain the phenomena I stated above.

Comment: Exactly. Everything in Javascript is an object. And interestingly as aside note this is exactly why you should never iterate through an array using the ' for (x in myArray) ' syntax for iterating through an array. It can do some unpredictable stuff.

Comment: @SamRedway That is not strictly true. For example `42` is not an object; nor is `"Hello world!"`. It would be more accurate to say that *an array is a special/magical kind of object* (the length property, and when it is updated being a good example).

Comment: Yes thats a fair point. I guess saying 'everything' is an object was a bit gungho :)

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! I thought I had it right, but just wanted to make sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To formalise my answer. This is exactly correct. Barring literals and temporary values pretty much everything in JavaScript is an object. Including functions, arrays, and variables.

It is for this exact reason that it is considered dangerous to iterate through an array with the syntax:

```
for (x in myArray){}
```

The above line of code could lead to unpredictable results!

This approach of creating all data types as objects allows JavaScript to be as dynamic and flexible as it is.

You can see the full description of Object [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

Comment: ... and allows JavaScript to be incredibly WTF, as shown in many examples, including this kind of iteration and these examples: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat